# SQL Server Reporting Studio report showing "ERROR#" or invalid data type error

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I struggled with this issue for too long before finally tracking down how to avoid/fix it. It seems like something that should be on StackOverflow for the benefit of others.

I had an SSRS report where the query worked fine and displayed the string results I expected. However, when I tried to add that field to the report, it kept showing "ERROR#". I was eventually able to find a little bit more info:

> The Value expression used in [textbox] returned a data type that is
>   not valid.

But, I knew my data was valid.

Comment: mark your answer as the answer

Comment: I have to wait 2 days.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fad557d1-f32b-4291-a5ef-33220a99fa1b/the-value-expression-used-in-textrun-textboxparagraphs0textruns0-returned-a-data-type-that?forum=sqlreportingservices).

Basically, it's a problem with caching and you need to delete the ".data" file that is created in the same directory as your report. Some also suggested copying the query/report to a new report, but that appears to be the hard way to achieve the same thing. I deleted the .data file for the report I was having trouble with and it immediately started working as-expected.

Comment: I changed a parameter, which invalidates the cache. It worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This was driving me insane!

Comment: Sometimes also closing / re-opening VS studio is required as well.

Comment: Just to be clear - you need to delete the .rdl.data file that belongs to the report. I spent some time looking for a file called .data before I worked it out.After that it works - thanks!

Comment: I want to know why the visual studio "clean" function doesn't remove these cached files, Like I would expect a "clean" process to do.

Comment: Makes absolute sense. I was actually wondering how my query, which took some time to load, could so instantly spit out results in my report each time. The caching as it pertains to the `.rdl.data` file completes the picture in my head. Fantastic and valuable information, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

After you preview the report, click the refresh button on the report and it will pull the data again creating an updated rdl.data file.

Comment: This is just of comment quality

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to this issue is to click *Refresh Fields* in the *Dataset Properties* menu.

This will update the list of fields, and force SSRS to get new data, rather than relying on a cached version.

Comment: This does not work. I clicked "Refresh Fields" and changed the name of the returning column. No dice. Deleting .data is the way.