# Why do I keep getting "The Value expression used in textrun returned a data type that is not valid." error?

Tags: reporting-services, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

My expression includes the `.Value` extensions on each of my fields and my assumption is that they are all the same "lookup" data type. As such, I cannot understand why I keep getting an error

> The Value expression used in textrun returned a data type that is not valid

I have tried everything from deleting the ".data" file to making sure to include the ".Value" extension. Does anyone know of any other possible causes of this issue? Is there a way to see what the data types returned are or convert them to something SSRS likes?

I attempted to convert the Source to a string with CStr but that did not help. I attempted to convert the Target Field but CStr cannot be used on the target table or the output Field.

I deleted the ".data" file as per this post: [SQL Server Reporting Studio report showing "ERROR#" or invalid data type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430839/sql-server-reporting-studio-report-showing-error-or-invalid-data-type-error)

```
=LookupSet(Fields!leadid.Value,Fields!regardingobjectidValue.Value,Fields!regardingobjectidValue.Value,"Activities")
```